# Background Position for image is not working properly in ipad3

Tags: html, css, background

Hi pls help someone to solve the issue. The Issue is Header Background image is not displaying properly in ipad3. My css and html code goes below. This works in fine in all desktop browsers. But the .headerhead background image is hidden in ipad3 browsers.

fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/jvandhana/CL6Ru/

```
 <div id="header">
    <div class="headerhead">
        <div class="headerdetail">
            My Task
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

#header {
    background: url("../images/bgheadgrey.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.headerhead {
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    background: url("../images/bgtitle_large1.png") no-repeat scroll center 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

Media Query for ipad3
/*iPad 3 & 4 Media Queries */

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    #header {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .headerhead {
        height: 60px;
        width: 600px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 999;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using any media query to target ipad?

Comment: yes im posting it with my question pls see my updateed question.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I feel like your media query is not targeting iPad3, can you find it out, may be by putting a different background color. Found a different media query for ipad3 here, please try this once https://halgatewood.com/ipad-3-media-query/

Comment: by the way, in the media query for iPad 3, the .headerhead is missing background image, you have to put background image here as well

Comment: @sajithNair Thnks for ur suggestions that ipad issue is cleared by calling the header background image in media query.

Comment: OK I will add as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the media query for iPad 3, the .headerhead is missing background image, you have to put background image here as well.